# what will be used in place of KafkaUtils in latest kafka version 0.10.1.1

Tags: apache-kafka

I have upgraded my kafka and also kafka-spark streaming, But I am facing some challanges while changing some of the  method of them . Like KafkaUtils is throwing error as well as Iterator is also throwing error . My Kafka version is 0.10.1.1 .
So If anyone have any idea that how to fix these changes that would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

KafkaUtils are part of Apache Spark Streaming, not part of Apache Kafka

org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

Comment: But that one is throwing some error and that's why we need to change the parameter of kafka utils and package also. SO if you can tell me that what will be the new package of kafkaUtils and parameter for topics and kafkaparams. That would be good.

Answer (score 0):

The previous package of KafkaUtils was "org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka". The latest package is "org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010".

For setting kafkaparams and topic details, check the following code snippet,

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import scala.Tuple2;

Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092");
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("topicA", "topicB");

final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
    streamingContext,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
  );

stream.mapToPair(
  new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
      return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
    }
  })
```

For further reference, visit the following link https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html